# Does localisation (of modules) cancel.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, localization, module-isomorphism

If I have two modules $R$ and $M$ and I take the [localisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)) of both then do we have,

$$\frac{S^{-1}R}{S^{-1}M}\cong\frac{R}{M}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No in general since localization is an exact functor one has it commutes with quotients, so \begin{equation} \frac{S^{-1}(M)}{S^{-1}(N)}\cong S^{-1}\left(\frac{M}{N}\right)
\end{equation}
So an easy counter example is taking $N=0$ and $M=\mathbb{Z}/(2)$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ them one has:
\begin{equation} \frac{S^{-1}(M)}{S^{-1}(N)}\cong0, \frac{M}{N}\cong\mathbb{Z}/(2)
\end{equation}